# Running daemonized Ruby script

Tags: ruby, daemon

I have a Ruby script that runs just fine on its own when I call

```
$ruby backup.rb
```

I am now trying to daemonize running that script, following instructions from http://daemons.rubyforge.org/ by creating a backup_controller.rb file like this

```
#in backup_controller.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run('backup.rb')
```

When I try to run the program with

```
$ruby backup_controller.rb start        #also with run
```

I get a permission denied error. I've tried updating all of the permissions for the involved files with chmod +x, but nothing is changing. Since the backup.rb runs just fine on its own, I assume the issue has to be with it being called via daemon. Any insight as the why this might be the case?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: The exact errors says <Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - log>. It may be specific to the code in backup.rb, I'm just confused why it will work when called on its own and not when called through the daemon.

Comment: When you daemonize, you loose access to file creation, and possibly writing. Do you try to open a log in backup.rb?

Comment: Yes, actually. I use FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(config.log_dest)), and then try to make a new Logger and debug. Would that be throwing an exception?

Comment: I think that should be the cause. Try using syslog instead.

Comment: Syslog in replacement of logger? I will give it a try, thank you!

Comment: Exactly. Use the syslog library to output information to your system log. It will only work on Unixes, but Daemons only does too, so I assume you're not on Windows.